# How to get OperationDescription from OperationContext on AfterReceiveRequest in WCF?

Tags: wcf

In my implementation of IDispatchMessageInspector on the AfterReceiveRequest
I want to check if an OperationBehavior is applied on the current operation being called.
So I need to access OperationDescription of the operation that's about to get invoked??
Any direct way instead of having to compare the Action of the current operation with all the in the DispatchRuntime?

Thanks..

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and solved through below way.

```
OperationContext ctx = OperationContext.Current;
ServiceDescription hostDesc = ctx.Host.Description;
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = hostDesc.Endpoints.Find(ctx.IncomingMessageHeaders.To);
string operationName = ctx.IncomingMessageHeaders.Action.Replace(
  endpoint.Contract.Namespace + endpoint.Contract.Name + "/", "");
OperationDescription operation =
endpoint.Contract.Operations.Find(operationName);
```

This is suggested solution at [msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/67a48c14-48fb-4953-909c-da9aa2fc6b43)

Answer (score 2):

The suggested answer by Noel Bj Kim works, except this line is problematic:

```
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = hostDesc.Endpoints.Find(ctx.IncomingMessageHeaders.To);
```

I've found that when hosting a WCF service in IIS, the Uri used in the service may not exactly match the one being requested - in my case "localhost" was requested but the service was actually using the machine name (e.g. "pc1.domain1.net"), not "localhost".

My solution, which may not work for everyone's circumstances, is to just do a partial match based on the scheme and the path. This effectively allows a match of `http://localhost/Service1` to `http://pc1.domain.net/Service1`.

```
/// <summary>
/// Find a service endpoint by partially matching the uri, but only against the Scheme and PathAndQuery elements.
/// This avoids issues with IIS hosting, where the actual Uri stored in the ServiceEndpoint may not exactly
/// match the one used in configuration.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">Uri to match against</param>
/// <returns>A matching ServiceEndpoint, or null if no match was found.</returns>
private ServiceEndpoint FindServiceEndpointBySchemeAndQuery(Uri uri)
{
    foreach (var endpoint in OperationContext.Current.Host.Description.Endpoints)
    {
        if (endpoint.Address.Uri.Scheme == uri.Scheme
            && endpoint.Address.Uri.PathAndQuery == uri.PathAndQuery)
        {
            return endpoint;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Called like this:

```
ServiceEndpoint endpoint = FindServiceEndpointBySchemeAndQuery(ctx.IncomingMessageHeaders.To);
```